# Proof: Angle between two diagonals of a parallelogram

Tags: geometry, trigonometry, euclidean-geometry, angle

Can anyone prove the angle $\theta$ (smaller angle) between diagonals of a parallelogram is given by the equation

$$\cos(\theta)=\frac{a-c}{a+c}$$

where $2a$ is the base length of parallelogram; $2c$ is the horizontal distance to the edge when we draw a vertical line as seen in the picture below.

[image]

I have been trying to get this but haven't had a success. Thanks for your help in advance.

Comment: what exactly have you tried?

Comment: I tried to get everything in terms of angles of side edges but I can't really get to the (a-c)/(a+c), which seems an easy expression, I tried using law of cos and sin at some point too, but no success. Any suggestions?

Comment: can you find or construct a triangle with hypotenuse $a+c$ and adjacent $a-c$?

Comment: I tried what you said to get a right triangle of (a+c) hypotenuse n adjacent (a-c) on the sketch, but I couldn't get any.

Comment: Hi again everyone, I tried to get the answer to my question finally using vector notations and dot product, which is equivalent to law of cosines at the end and I realized that I am probably misunderstanding the question. I better post the problem from zero without any assumption so that it won't get messed up. Is it better to create a new post or do you know if I can modify this post?

Comment: To modify the question, Just click the 'edit' button below the tags.

Comment: The result is not correct. Put $c=0$, you will get a rectangle and by your formula, $\cos(\theta) = 1 \implies \theta = 0$, which is clearly not the case.